# C# HostBuilder logging configuration. Non-generic logger is null

Tags: c#, logging, .net-core

I have a dotnet core 3.0 console app with the following packages installed:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="3.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="3.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="3.0.1" />
```

Here is my entire minimal, reproduceable complete program:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace logging
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureLogging((context, b) =>
                {
                    b.AddConsole();
                })
                .Build();

            var logger = host.Services.GetService<ILogger>();
            var genericLogger = host.Services.GetService<ILogger<Program>>();
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to resolve the two loggers, the generic one gets resolved okay but the non-generic one is always null. Can anyone spot why my non-generic logger is null please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because `ILogger` specifically is not added to the service collection. Only the generic

```
/// <summary>
/// Adds logging services to the specified <see cref="IServiceCollection" />.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="services">The <see cref="IServiceCollection" /> to add services to.</param>
/// <param name="configure">The <see cref="ILoggingBuilder"/> configuration delegate.</param>
/// <returns>The <see cref="IServiceCollection"/> so that additional calls can be chained.</returns>
public static IServiceCollection AddLogging(this IServiceCollection services, Action<ILoggingBuilder> configure)
{
    if (services == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));
    }

    services.AddOptions();

    services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<ILoggerFactory, LoggerFactory>());
    services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(Logger<>)));

    services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IConfigureOptions<LoggerFilterOptions>>(
        new DefaultLoggerLevelConfigureOptions(LogLevel.Information)));

    configure(new LoggingBuilder(services));
    return services;
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/master/src/Logging/Logging/src/LoggingServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L42)

To prove this point, if one was to invoke the following using your example

```
var logger = host.Services.GetRequiredService<ILogger>();
```

It would throw an exception that it is unable to resolve the requested type.

`ILogger` is not normally used for explicit injection or resolution, but rather as a base type for assignment

For example

```
public class AboutModel : PageModel {
    private readonly ILogger logger;

    public AboutModel(ILogger<AboutModel> logger) {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    //...
}
```

Or in a non-host console app application

```
var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder => {
    builder.AddConsole();
});

ILogger logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Program>();
```

Reference [Logging in .NET Core and ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/)